# Django query how to write: 'WHERE field LIKE' in Cassandra

Tags: django, cassandra, cql

What is the equivalent of this CQLSH statement in Django?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE string LIKE '%pattern%';
```

How do I implement this in django? I tried

```
result = table.objects.filter(string__contains='pattern')
```

but it is giving the following error

```
[Invalid query] message="Cannot use CONTAINS on non-collection column string"
```

I have already made a custom index for the search field and raw LIKE query is working in cqlsh. But I need something for Django to filter on basis of keyword. Thanks in advance

Comment: try this one may worked : `result = table.objects.all().filter(string__contains='pattern')` if not add your model in the question

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation for cqlengine on [Filtering Operators](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/cqlengine/queryset/#filtering-operators):

The `CONTAINS` operator is used for collections:

> The CONTAINS operator is available for all collection types (List,
> Set, Map).

For your need you want to use the `LIKE` operator:

```
result = table.objects.filter(string__like='%pattern%').allow_filtering()
```